# Build a Java Rest API with Intellij

Tags: restful-authentication, jira-rest-api, java

I need help developing a Basic Java Rest API using IntelliJ and terminal on my mac. I also have docker installed. I want to run a hello world on local host using the REST API Style

Answer (score 1):

There's a ton of different java web frameworks that will help you build a REST endpoint. Here's some of those frameworks:

- http://spring.io/
- https://vertx.io/
- https://www.playframework.com/

if you want to build it from scratch (not recommended) then checkout
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm